# Exclude some css files from a vue-cli bundle

Tags: webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I have a vue cli project and I'm trying to exclude css files from being bundled in `chunk-vendors.css`

The reason being, that I have a theme file included in my app that overrides all of the styles of a library and those library's styles are not needed anymore

The files in question are located in `node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/*.css`

I can't seem to find the configuration that I need to change in my `vue.config.js` file

My simplified `vue.config.js`:

```js
const prefixer = require('postcss-prefix-selector');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    css: {
        extract: true,
        loaderOptions: {
            postcss: {
                // This is a workaround to add specificity to the app's theme
                // to correctly override all the rules I'm trying to remove
                plugins: () => [
                    prefixer({
                        prefix: 'body',
                        exclude: [/body .*/]
                    }),
                    autoprefixer({})
                ],
                // This doesn't seem to do anything
                exclude: path.resolve('node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk')
            },
        }
    },
};
```

But the files don't get excluded

What option should I use to exclude css files from my bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, when adding element-ui with vue-cli-plugin-element

The plugin added some lines to `babel.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  'presets': [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ],
  'plugins': [
    // The following was added by vue-cli-plugin-element
    [
      'component',
      {
        'libraryName': 'element-ui',
        'styleLibraryName': 'theme-chalk'
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

By changing it to:

```js
module.exports = {
  'presets': [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ],
  'plugins': [
    // The following was added by vue-cli-plugin-element
    [
      'component',
      {
        'libraryName': 'element-ui',
        'style': false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I got rid of the useless css imports